# MySQL where clause with microseconds

Tags: mysql

I've a table with an id (int) and a time datetime(6) column.

Selecting by id works fine:

```
SELECT id,time FROM event where id = 570054;
=> 570054   2017-02-17 13:25:40.043000
```

But selecting by time with microseconds will not work:

```
SELECT id,time FROM event where time = '2017-02-17 12:25:40.043000';
=> No DATA
```

I do the queries in mysql Workbenchb 6.3. The MySQL Server version is 5.6.33 which  should support microseconds (as seen in the first query)

What am I missing? Why will the second query not work?

Comment: If your timestamps are off by a tenth of a millisecond you don't get the hit.  Better to give a range.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a matter of the resolution of the time value.  Start with a range comparison like this:

```
SELECT id, time
FROM event 
WHERE time >= '2017-02-17 12:25:40.043' AND
      time < '2017-02-17 12:25:40.044';
```

Answer (score 0):

Ouch! Sorry ;-)

Everything works correct, when I don't mess with timezones.

The time value is at **13**:25:40 and not at **12**:25:40.
Query with

```
 SELECT id,time FROM event where time = '2017-02-17 13:25:40.043000';
```

works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Remove quotes from your query. 
**Correct**
SELECT id,time FROM event where time = 2017-02-17 12:25:40.043000;